# Looking for cyborg movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie must have been from the 70s or 80s. I don't remember the plot, just some images. I believe there are several cyborgs in a room waiting to go do something. Most of the movie might take place in this one room. I remember early on in the movie the cyborgs are all suspicious of each other (the other cyborgs in the room).

Additional points;

- They might not all be cyborgs.
- There might be a scene with a cyborg penis at some point (or this is could be from a different movie).
- The movie had a very dark mood.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 2):

It is a long shot, but:

It could be [**Inquest of Pilot Pirx**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquest_of_Pilot_Pirx), [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080010/), from **1979**:

[image]

In this movie some significant part takes place in the cabin of the spacecraft 'Goliath'. **The crew consist of astronauts, humans, and non-humans (called 'nonlinears'). No one knows about others occupation (human or non-human), and so they suspect each other (trying to figure out who is human and who is robot).** Some of them report to the captain about possible 'occupation' of the other crew members.

**Plot summary**

> Spaceship pilot Pirx is hired for a mission to test probes to be
> placed in the Cassini Division, a gap between rings of Saturn, while
> the real secret goal was to evaluate some nonlinears (androids with
> "nonlinear" characteristics) for use as crew members on future space
> flights. The mission meets with a near disaster and the human crew are
> almost killed.
>
> Upon returning to Earth there is an inquest to determine if Pirx was
> responsible for the accident. Pirx recounts the events and in the end
> it is established that **one of the robots caused the malfunction of a
> probe and attempted to pass through the Division to launch the probe
> manually, an attempt which would kill the human crew members** and prove
> the superiority of nonlinears over humans.